# INitiate SMS by sending ussd request

Tags: gsm, telephony, ussd

Is there any way to initiate an SMS MO from a device from the network. Eg: Can I send a special USSD push to a device from the network so that it will SMS a specified text to a specified number from the device.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you are the network operator and the USSD message is defined in the network and supported by the device.
You could also send a MT SMS and get the specified text as a reply (again supported on the device, obviously).

Comment: I have access to operator's network..Can you please elaborate "You could also send a MT SMS and get the specified text as a reply". Also can this happen without user intervention?

Comment: Yes, it could happen without user intervention if you can control the SMS receiving software on the device. Probably USSD is simpler, if you can define a USSD message, and also have access to the USSD module on the device, because this is one of the main functions of the USSD module (to receive and process messages), whereas the SMS module on the device may not be set up to process incoming SMSs in this way.  Unless it's an embedded device, and you can control everything, of course.

Answer (score 0):

This largely depends on the device capabilities. The device needs logic for processing the USSD message, instead of just displaying it, and to trigger sending the MO SMS.

Since this is not a factory configuration, you would need a custom application to be installed on the device, provided that the device platform allows for the needed functionality. For example some J2ME-capable devices do have this functionality. Consult your device manufacturers development documentation.